# WindowFromPoint doesn't work correctly on 64bit .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, 64-bit

I wrote the easy test program by C# and .NET 4.0.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(int xPoint, int yPoint);

Point pt = MousePosition;
IntPtr w = WindowFromPoint(pt.X, pt.Y);
```

If this builts as 32bit, it works. But if it builds as 64bit, an unrelated window handle will return. Are there a solution or alternatives?

Comment: Windows XP Pro 64 bit - running 32 bit app WindowFromPoint takes 2 32 bit integers off the stack regardless of what the documentation says.

Comment: hi Prl. Please substantiate statements with official or accepted authorities. A statement like this would be welcome as a comment but not as an answer. I appreciate that at rep 1, you're unable to make comments, but this would not be considered a "good" or "acceptable" type of answer.

Comment: @Pri, you made an strong statement, but did not point on how to solve the problem. Try to give an alternative for Tank2005 to do what he wants and to give some references or tests to prove what you said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right, that won't work.  WindowFromPoint() does **not** take two arguments, it only takes one.  A structure of type POINT.  You got away with it in 32-bit code by sheer accident, that luck ran out in 64-bit mode since it passes arguments a different way.

Use the pinvoke.net web site to find the correct pinvoke declaration.

Comment: I accepted the advices on the Internet without question. I'm going to set an argument to POINT instantly.

Comment: Sadly, PInvoke.net lists the two-argumented alternative as well, which is just plain wrong :/